# Is there a working front-end for ctez on Ghostnet?

Tags: testnet, ghostnet, ctez

Is there a working front-end for ctez on Ghostnet?

> ctez.vercel.app/

```
  doesn't work
```

> ctez-testnet.netlify.app/

```
doesn't work
```

PS: why aren't there tags for Ghostnet and Ctez.?

Comment: IDK if it is the reason of your question, but if you need cTez for testing your app on ghostnet you can get cTez from Marigold's faucet https://faucet.marigold.dev/
We deployed a cTez contract at KT1Q4ecagDAmqiY3ajvtwfNZyChWy86W7pzb

Comment: I've added those tags with some brief descriptions, thanks for pointing out that they were missing